# Visual Studio trick go to certain lines back and forth

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010

Is there a short cut to go to certain lines? I know I can do ctrl-G then enter line. But I want to go back and forth between line 350 and line 788 quickly and easily. easier than ctr G line.  is there a trick to create the short cuts?

Comment: Assuming you are using Visual Studio, you could use bookmarks

Comment: You might want to try the `View.NavigateBack` and `View.NavigateForward` commands. They're bound to keys `Ctrl-Minus` and `Ctrl-Shift-Minus` for me.  They are also on the `Standard` toolbar by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also split the window so you can see both lines at the same time. Click on the window menu then click split. View line 350 in the top and 788 in the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

You can create **bookmarks** with Ctrl-K+Ctrl+K and then navigate between those bookmarks using Ctrl+K+Ctrl+N (next bookmark) and Ctrl+K+Ctrl+P (previous).

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Bookmarks** within all versions of Visual Studio:

Create a bookmark (on the current line): <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>

Jump to next bookmark: <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>